# set primary key `id`

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Table:

`ProductComapny`

Fields:`id`,`name`

`ProductComapny` content 10000 recorde.

now i want `id` set primary key But a number of `id` recordings have been repeated

1.how can `id` set primary key???

2.how can remove duplicate recorde?

3.How can I get the number of duplicate records?

BY SQL  In SqlServer And MySql

For Study

Comment: This is marked both `mysql` and `sql server`.  **WHICH IS IT?**

Comment: sql sql sql sql sql no matter sql server or mysql

Comment: @JNK - LOL, Good Spot.  @ ashkufarax - It matters a whole lot, MySQL and SQL Server have different operations available to each other; they do different things, in different ways, with different syntax.  My answer, for example, will NOT work in MySQL.

Comment: -1 for `no matter sql server or mysql` - it actually **DOES** matter if you want a correct answer.

Comment: in sql server amd mysql for study

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered for `SQL Server` - This won't work in `MySQL`.  Please specify which, rather than patronising people who are able to help you.

To get the count of duplicates:

```
SELECT id, name, COUNT(*) FROM productCompany GROUP BY id, name
```

To apply a primary key, first delete the duplicates as follows:

```
WITH sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, name) AS duplicate_id,
    id,
    name
  FROM
    productCompany
)
DELETE
  sorted
WHERE
  duplicate_id > 1
```

Then use Management Studio to apply your primary key.

Comment: How can I get the number of duplicate records?

Comment: I realize question is tagged as both SQL Server and MySQL. Note that here are no window functions (`ROW_NUMBER() OVER...`) in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

3.How can I get the number of duplicate records?

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*)
    FROM ProductCompany
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

2.how can remove duplicate records?

How would you choose which one to keep?

Comment: the `HAVING` clause is redundant in this case (you will not get any rows with non-existent `id`s anyway, so there's no point in filtering them out)

Comment: @Piskvor : It says `> 1` not `> 0`.  This means that records that exist but have ***no duplicates*** are not included in Joe's results.

Comment: @Piskvor: The `HAVING` clause filters out instances where the ID occurs only once and is therefore not duplicated.

Comment: Ah, true - I was thinking along the lines "how many times is this particular ID in the db?" and didn't catch the "non-duplicate" IDs.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about MySQL, then this will do:

ad 3: `SELECT COUNT(*),id FROM ProductComapny GROUP BY id` will give you a count of occurences of each id in the database (btw "ProductCom *ap* ny"?)

ad 2: that depends on your business logic - which do you want to keep?

ad 1: `ALTER TABLE ProductComapny ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);`

(yes, the MySQL/MSSQL difference matters: IIRC neither of the above is valid code in MSSQL)

Comment: I think your queries are valid TSQL

Comment: @JNK: I'm not sure about the mix of group functions and non-group fields in a SELECT query; that used to be a MySQL-only quirk. Possibly it's implemented in TSQL now? (IDK)

Comment: @Piskovr - It's always been allowed in TSQL **as long as you group by the non-aggregated fields**.  Mysql allows `SELECT col1, col2, COUNT(*) from table GROUP BY col1` while TSQL does not.

Answer (score 1):

if you force mysql to add a primary key, it going to remove all duplicate to be able to succsed, you can force a alternatetion of a table whit the keyword ignore, that ignore warnings.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE ProductComapny ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove duplicate entries is to copy them into temp table, delete all duplicates from main table, copy data from temp to main.

insert into TempTable
select id, name
from ProductComapny
group by id, name
having count(*) > 1

delete from ProductComapny
where id in (select id from TempTable)

insert into ProductComapny
select id, name
from TempTable

This should work.
After that you can set primary key on ID field since there will be no more duplicates.